# jQuery give response after an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, submit, response

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $("form#fbox").submit(function(){ 
 var msg = $("input#ibox").val(); 
 $.get("foo.php", {m: msg}, function(data){
   $('#display').html(data);
 });
 return false; 
 });
});
```

i have this jquery script wherein it creates a post request "invisibly" after submitting the form. thus not refreshing the page. the problem is how can i get the response of the foo.php or rather what will i put in foo.php to give back a response?

for example i inputted *'hello'*, how can i display *'hi'* on **#display**? something like that xD

Comment: lol thanks guys sorry for being a dumbass..i haven't tried this ajax thing yet thats why im kind of freaking out when there's something i can't solve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have `foo.php` echo whatever content you want to go inside the element that corresponds to `#display` -- no more, no less.  So this would work:

```
echo 'hi';
```

Comment: Or simply just 'hi' outside the <?php ?> block

Comment: Right. Whatever will render 'hi' to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Put whatever you need in foo.php.  The contents of that html page will be placed into #display.

Answer (score 0):

You're already setting the contents of `#display` to whatever the script outputs.

The 3rd argument to `$.get` is a callback which is execute on success.

Answer (score 0):

In your php file you should echo anything you want to return.  So if you want your response to say 'Hello World' your php file would look like:

```
<?
    echo "Hello World";
?>
```

Your JavaScript looks like it is handling it properly.